# How to delete a model entirely, including contact filter

Tags: gazebo

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

Hi,

In my application I need to dynamically insert, delete and reinsert models. So when I delete a module and reinsert the same module at the same position with the same name, I will get an error which is

```
Error [ContactManager.cc:267] Filter with the same name already exists! Aborting
```

Meanwhile, I found that the object of the model is still there even after I 'delete' it use the function provided, which I believe is "Fini()".

So I ran a little test, which I added several lines in front of and after my delete function as follows

```
cout<<"World: This is a count of the object left: "<<currentWorld->GetModel(module_name).use_count()<<endl;
currentWorld->GetModel(module_name)->Fini();
cout<<"World: This is a count of the object left: "<<currentWorld->GetModel(module_name).use_count()<<endl;
```

Before I finalize the model, the count of the model instances are 23, and after that operation, the count drop to 7 instead of 1. I checked my entire code again and make sure I reset all the model_ptr instance I used. Therefore, it seems that we can never delete a model entirely.

Is this a bug or I massed something up in my code? Is there a solution without changing the name of the new inserted model? This functionality is crucial to our applications, so please help me!

By the way, the gazebo I used is 1.9.5. Have this been fixed in the new version?

Oh, also

```
currentWorld->GetPhysicsEngine()->GetContactManager()->GetContacts().size()
```

always gives me zero, so I don't know how to manually delete contact filter either.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.gazebosim.org/question/6369/how-to-delete-a-model-entirely,-including-contact-filter/) by [EdwardC](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/484/edwardc/) on Gazebo Answers with karma: 38 on 2014-06-07

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

There is an [existing issue about removing models](https://bitbucket.org/osrf/gazebo/issue/1177/removing-moving-model-with-ode-friction) and there is a [pending pull request to add a better API function to solve this problem](https://bitbucket.org/osrf/gazebo/pull-request/1106/added-world-removemodel-to-fix-issue-1177/diff) (World::RemoveModel).

---

Originally posted by [scpeters](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/109/scpeters/) with karma: 2861 on 2014-06-09

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [EdwardC](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/484/edwardc/) on 2014-06-11**:
By the way, could you show me how to manually disable the contact filters of the models which have already been deleted?